# How to know if page is odd or even?

Tags: mpdf

I’m trying to create a layout with mPDF 6.1 as follows:

[image]

I got everything working (with `mirrorMargins` option) except the position of the landscape images. I’m able to set a width with CSS that exceeds the width defined by the page margins, but to position the image correctly (I could do so with a negative margin), I would have to know if the image is on an odd or even page.

Is there a way to "know" that with CSS? Or via PHP the moment the image is added to the PDF? Or does someone see another, simpler way to accomplish this kind of layout?

Comment: :nth-child(odd)/:nth-child(even)

Comment: :nth-child won’t help here as it is not related to a (printed) page.

Comment: ah yes of course